# Page is not redirecting to updated URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I need to redirect to new URL for my application. I have an event on which I am changing the URL. Here URL is updated but page is not redirected. It only redirects after refresh. Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

JS:

```
 _onNewFlowCreated(newFlow) {
        let url= '/#/flows/'+ newFlow.uid +'/edit';
        //window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
         window.location.href= url;
    }
```

I tried using `react-router`. But not found solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
import { Router, Redirect, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute, useRouterHistory, RouterContext, hashHistory } from 'react-router';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using reactjs use

```
browserHistory.push('/#/flows/'+ newFlow.uid +'/edit');
```

to navigate to another url

Comment: note you should have done an import first like: `import { browserHistory } from './react-router'`

Comment: if are accessing from a method you might have to use the `this` keyword as: `this.browserHistory.push('/#/flows/'+ newFlow.uid +'/edit');`

Comment: browserHistory is undefined.

Comment: did you use the `this` keyword

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103593/discussion-between-ved-and-ayo-k).